# Is it possible to connect a 65 twin reverb reissue to an audio interface?

Tags: amplifiers, audio

I am planning to get a Fender 65 twin reverb reissue, and I am wondering if it's possible to connect it to an audio interface, a Focusrite 2i4, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a 2i4 you have the option of using two inputs so I would suggest tracking either two microphones (for instance an SM57 on the cone, and something sweet like an Aston Spirit or another LDC of your choice on room mic, a couple of foot back to try and get the developed sound of the room.)

This should give you the option of developing a nice balanced tone on each and every take.

Failing this, and since the amp in question is a tube amp I would advise against, muting the speakers and going with some form of DI as mentioned above as this can be detrimental to the speaker circuit. You'd be better suited with an attenuator so the amp actually feels like it has some form of load (resistance) on it

Comment: I love putting two mics on a guitar amp, but I rarely work in a room that sounds good enough to have a room mic. So another way to do this might be to put the 57 on one cone and an LDC on the other. Assuming the time alignment is good, it gives you the ability to get some nice rock midrange from the 57 and then fill in the clarity and highs and lows with the LDC. Either way, +1 for the two mics idea.

Comment: Todd is not recommending bypassing the speaker, merely running the signal from the  aux. speaker out (with appropriate impedance) to the soundcard, i.e. something like this: http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/TorpedoLive?adpos=1t1&creative=105744829081&device=c&matchtype=b&network=g&gclid=CjwKEAjwguu5BRDq8uSKhaKIzDkSJACQ7WJlWcQYj-maczdr6kDWDzbqDj3AwqTlKB0nHrW_mpWF0RoC47zw_wcB

Comment: Well, yes, if you've a pretty boring sounding room you can put both close without worrying about phase issues. And that's generally why I'd go Dyn / LDC combo too. But I'd suggest at least trying a few rooms as a tube amp turned up LOUD can really create some interesting harmonic resonances in the room that make using the LDC all that much sweeter.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to record an amp like that would be to put a mic in front of it and connect the mic to the interface.

The second best way would be to use a speaker simulator/DI that can be inserted in between the speaker out of the amp and the speakers, and then the XLR out from the speaker sim/DI would be connected to the interface.

It does not seem to have a line output or any other kind of output so those are probably your only options.